# Как копировать значение из списка в другой с заменой?

Tags: python, list

Создаю список:

```
a =[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,
    1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,10,10]
```

длинной 43. Затем создаю этой же длинны список `list = [0] * 43` с нулями.

Есть два других списка `oa` и `ab`.

```
oa = [4.0, 5.0, 8.0]
ob = [2.0, 3.0, 10.0]
```

Если в `oa` есть значение 4 и оно есть в списке `а`, то напротив 4 в списке `a` ставим 1 в списке `list`.
Если в `ob` есть значение 3 и оно есть в списке `а`, то напротив 3 в списке `a` ставим 2 в списке `list`.
Тоесть для `oa` соответсвующее значение 1, для `ob` оно 2.

Как в итоге получить такой список:

```
a = [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
     0,0,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.zeros_like(a)
res[np.isin(a, oa)] = 1
res[np.isin(a, ob)] = 2
```

результат:

```
In [150]: res
Out[150]:
array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2])
```

Comment: @kocwab, `res = np.full_like(a, 5, dtype="int16")` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - чистый питон с двойным тернарным оператором и списковым сокращением:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,10,10]
oa = [4.0, 5.0, 8.0]
ob = [2.0, 3.0, 10.0]
b = [1 if i in oa else 2 if i in ob else 0 for i in a]
print(b)
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]
```